# Find the process that consumed the memory

Tags: linux, memory, top

The box has 96GB memory, no swap.

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         96714      85762      10952          0         94       2185
-/+ buffers/cache:      83482      13232
Swap:            0          0          0
```

It looks like 85GB memory are in use, but from top command, sort by `%MEM`

Only 32GB memory are in use, where did the rest go?

[image]

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

```
# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:         99036140     kB
MemFree:          10901516     kB
Buffers:          126816       kB
Cached:           2355968      kB
SwapCached:       0            kB
Active:           35103352     kB
Inactive:         2973732      kB
Active(anon):     34352040     kB
Inactive(anon):   1793248      kB
Active(file):     751312       kB
Inactive(file):   1180484      kB
Unevictable:      1892         kB
Mlocked:          0            kB
SwapTotal:        0            kB
SwapFree:         0            kB
Dirty:            8864         kB
Readahead:        0            kB
Writeback:        0            kB
AnonPages:        35596308     kB
Mapped:           693268       kB
Shmem:            549000       kB
Slab:             48846688     kB
SReclaimable:     48771520     kB
SUnreclaim:       75168        kB
KernelStack:      9864         kB
PageTables:       108668       kB
NFS_Unstable:     0            kB
Bounce:           0            kB
WritebackTmp:     0            kB
CommitLimit:      49518068     kB
Committed_AS:     41937368     kB
VmallocTotal:     34359738367  kB
VmallocUsed:      500436       kB
VmallocChunk:     34290219936  kB
HugePages_Total:  0
HugePages_Free:   0
HugePages_Rsvd:   0
HugePages_Surp:   0
Hugepagesize:     2048         kB
DirectMap4k:      7252         kB
DirectMap2M:      100620288    kB
```

Comment: did you try running other memory analysis tools, which might help understanding which number holds the correct memory usage?

Comment: @Yaron what tools do you recommend?

Comment: which unix flavor are you using?

Comment: @Yaron It's centos 6.X

Comment: before running GUI tools, can you please execute `cat /proc/meminfo`?

Comment: @Yaron I don't have a GUI, attached meminfo

Answer (score 0):

Total Memory = Free Memory + Cache/Buffers + Active + Inactive

```
         = 10901516 + 126816 + 2355968 + 35103352 + 2973732
         = 51461384 KB
         = 49 GB
```

Missing Memory = 96 GB - 49 GB 
               = 47 GB 
The missing memory almost equal to Slab Memory (48846688 kB ) , I am guessing that there some kernel module is leaking memory.

Please print /proc/slabinfo & slabtop command output to investigate more, and also print the output of vmware-toolbox-cmd stat balloon & vmware-toolbox-cmd stat memlimit if you're running on vmware.

**Edit**

It look like there is dentry kernel module consuming 48646536kB , searching the internet I found https://serverfault.com/questions/561350/unusually-high-dentry-cache-usage , it suggest that issue come from The culprit was a NSS (Network Security Services) library bundled with Libcurl

> You only have to upgrade nss-softokn (which has a required dependency
>   on nss-utils) at a minimum. and to get the benefit, you need to set
>   the environment variable NSS_SDB_USE_CACHE for the process that is
>   using libcurl. the presence of that environment variable is what
>   allows the costly non-existent file checks to be skipped."

Give it try and let us know.

Comment: slabinfo https://pastebin.com/d3BvL84q

Comment: slabtop https://postimg.org/image/i6wmu6wmn/